# How to render a rails template in a controller `rescue_from`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I want to render an error page and pass in an error message inside a `rescue_from` section in a Rails controller. It looks like this currently:

```
rescue_from ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature do
    render json: { errors: I18n.t(:invalid_token, scope: :errors) }, status: :bad_request
end
```

But we no longer want to render json. We want to render a rails template. How do we do this but also passing in the `errors` hash? Can this be done inside a `rescue_from`?

Answer (score 0):

A common way of responding when there are errors is by using an `exceptions_app` for your application, first create a controller to serve the error responses:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def not_found
    @details = "foo bar, something that happened in this request"
    render status: 404
  end

  def internal_server_error
    render status: 500
  end
end
```

You can assign instance vars in the controller, like ordinary controller actions, here you can build a message to the user or handle it however you like.

Then you can add some routes in your router:

```
match "/404", to: "errors#not_found", via: :all
match "/500", to "errors#internal_server_error", via: :all
```

In you application.rb file, add:

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

And last be sure to remove the 404.html and 500.html in your public dir if they are present.

NOTE:

If you want to see these pages locally during development you'll need to modify your `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```